# Connect to Access or SqlLite database on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, sqlite, ms-access, mono, connection-string

How do i connect to a Access or SqlLite (v.3) on a Mac website using Mono?

I got an Access database. My C# project could connect to my database while running on Windows.

My Access database file (.mdb file) is currently located in a Database folder on my application.

Im getting an error connecting to the database. My current SqlLite connection string looks like this: URI=/Database/Web1.db

I have tried a DSN to connect to the Access database without luck.
Does anyone have some experience connecting to a database on a Mac using Mono.

Im developing in Visual Studion on a Mac.

Comment: Connecting to sqlite is something very different from connecting to Access. Which one are you asking about? Note that you can't use the standard Microsoft ODBC driver for Access since it's not macOS compatible, you need to use [mdbtools](https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools)

Comment: Im from a Windows environment, so i dont have any experience with C source code projects. Doesn't MDBTools deliver an assembly for providing the connection.

Comment: MDBTools has multiple components, including an ODBC driver you might be able to use. It only does reads, though. My experience is limited. Did some research into porting an application using an Access database to  macOS, but finally it was considered too much work for too little result. If you have the option to go sqlite, do that, there are many different ways of connecting to an sqlite database from C#. You can do weird ODBC -> ODBC-JDBC bridge -> UCanAccess things if you need write access.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I switched to the SqlLite connection string again. It now seems to find my SqlLite copy of the Access database. Now im getting an InvalidCastException, thats a progress.